# How to query entries written in a specific locale? (Craft 3)

Tags: templating, craft3, localization, query

In Craft 2 you used to be able to do something like `{% set entries = craft.entries.section('something').locale('de') %}` but `.locale()` has been removed and there's nothing similar [in the docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html) that I see.

I'm aware that the locale automatically gets included based on the url, and I'm aware that "Locales" have been replaced by "Sites", but I want to force a query of entries from a specific locale on the one and only site I have regardless of what's in the URL. How can this be done?

Comment: When you have only one single site then what's the purpose of specifying the site id? Locals have been replaced by sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Craft 3, you can't really have locales. If in Craft 2 you had multiple locales, that should have been automatically migrated to multiple sites (as now the site is always single locale)

Having said that, you now need to use `site` or `siteId` parameter https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#site